# Using sed (or other command line programs) to delete every other X lines

Tags: sed, terminal, command, line

I have a huge text file that has several iterations of the same thing at different times, with a basic structure of:

```
Header (5 lines)
Data (thousands of lines)
Header (5 lines)
Data (thousands of lines)
Header (5 lines)
Data (thousands of lines)
```

This repeats and goes on for a while.

I want to cull this file, by removing every other set of Header + Data. I was thinking I'd use `sed`, but I can't figure out how.

It might be of help that each "cycle" starts with the same line (for the purpose of this example, imagine it says `Program X output`) and that exact line only appears once, at the beginning of each "cycle".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of how often you see the keywords, and print only when this count is an odd number:

```
awk '/Program X output/ {n++} n%2 == 1' <<END
Program X output
a
b
c
Program X output
d
e
Program X output
f
g
h
i
j
Program X output
m
n
o
END
```

```
Program X output
a
b
c
Program X output
f
g
h
i
j
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that completely solves it. Clearly, I need to learn how to use awk properly, I thought it was only useful for column editing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like all you need is:

```
awk '/Program X output/ && c++{exit} 1' file
```

e.g.

```
$ seq 50 | awk '/2/ && c++{exit} 1'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and show us concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/Program X output/{x;s/^/x/;x};G;/\n(x{2})*$/!P;d' file
```

When encountering a header line, add 1 to a counter in the hold space (HS). Append the HS to every line and only print the first line in the pattern space (PS) if the counter is a multiple of the required amount.